# controll the jetpack compose state with kotlin flow and seald class

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

hello developer I am new in  jetpack compose, I hadn't  problem
on controlling the state with coroutines and XML, then I tried to do the same thing in jetpack compose, but it did not work .my question is how to collect data with sealed state from view model class in jetpack compose.this  the function that i want to collect data on my UI compose

```
  fun getData()= flow<Resource<List<Task>>>
        {
            val accessToken=savedTokenClass.getSaveToken()
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            val result = authRepository.getUserTask()
          if (result.code() == 201) {
                emit(Resource.Success(result.body())          
             } 
          else {
               emit(Resource.Error(result.message()))
             }
        }
```

this my sealed class

```
   class Sealed open class Resource<T>() {
           class Success< T>(val data: T) : Resource<T>()
           class Loading<out >: Resource<out>()
           data  class Error< T>(val message: String, ) : Resource<T>()
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Composable Function:
Note: `resources` over here refers to the object of Resource sealed class that will be declared in viewModel itself.

```
private val viewModel: ViewModelClassName by viewModels()

val resourceState by remember(viewModel) { viewModel.resources}.collectAsState()

when(resourceState){
 is Resource.Loading->{/*TODO*/}
 is Resource.SUCCESS->{/*TODO*/}
 is Resource.Error->{/*TODO*/}
}
```